# VirtualBox and 64 bit incompatibility?

Tags: virtualbox, 64-bit, compatibility

I have the previous installed version of VBox. It is working well.

Today I tried to install VirtualBox 4.1.16.

But the OS said that setup is incompatible with the OS.

I don't understand, why my computer said this.

Win7/x64. 64 bit processor.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks for any advance!

Regards: dd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VirtualBox uses the same installer binary for both 32-bit Windows and 64-bit Windows, so that error is unexpected.  Try downloading it again from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads. It's possible the installer got corrupted somehow.

Comment: That was... Orbit corrupted the installer. Firefox downloaded it as well... :-)